# XA transaction in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-jms, xa

I am working on a POC. I have to achieve global transaction where my JMS listener persists the data in the database. In case any exception happens and persistence fails I want the JMS message to be sent back to queue.
From the research that I have done I have added

```java
@Transactional
@JmsListener(destination = "inbound.queue")
```

To my method and added the following dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

But this does not seem to help. Can someone suggest me what am I missing here? Any help would be highly appreciated.